# Secure some, but not all pages in a Grails application with the Shiro plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, shiro

Might be just me, but I have a hard time understanding how to secure just some of the pages in a Grails application with the Shiro Plugin.

I use this in my security filter:

```
class SecurityFilters {
  def filters = {
    all(uri: "/**") {
      before = {
        // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
        if (!controllerName) return true

        // Access control by convention.
        accessControl ( auth:false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I have created a user in my bootstrap:

```
    def adminRole = new Role(name: "Administrator")
    adminRole.addToPermissions("secured1")
    adminRole.addToPermissions("secured2:create,save,edit,update")
    adminRole.save()

    def user = new User(username: "admin", passwordHash: new Sha512Hash("***").toHex())
    user.addToRoles Role.findByName('Administrator')
    user.save()
```

and it works. Problem is, that it also secures all controllers/actions.

I was hoping, that it would be possible to NOT specify the actions I want to protect in my SecurityFilter, but only in the permissions.. But is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static property 'filter' allows you to define multiple filtering patterns. You can use the 'uri' parameter or the 'controller' parameter. If you use 'controller' you can also add an 'action' parameter. Each of these parameters takes a regular expression so you can do stuff like:

```
admin(uri:"/admin/**")
...
browseStore(controller:"store", action:"(show|list)")
...
shopStore(controller:"store", action:"*")
...
```

Check out http://www.grails.org/Filters for more info.

Comment: True, but my thought was that I could define that in the addToPermissions on the role, so I do not have to do it in the SecurityFilter. But thanks for your input

Comment: Filters are where access control happens. If you have some magic that allows you to apply access control by creating a permission, please share it. There is a discussion of wildcard permissions here: http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro

Notice that even though wildcard permissions might look similar to the controller:action:id layout that you are used to using in MVC that there is no relationship between these two when using the grails shiro plugin.

Comment: Hi Brandon: I know that the SecurityFilters are needed, but I don't want to write several of them. Just the one, and handle the rest of the permissions from the User and Role tables.

Comment: I do however recognize your answer as valid :-)